# XSLT 2.0 - How to replace '(' and ')' to empty from the string?

Tags: xslt, xpath, replace, xslt-2.0

I am looking for this solution in xslt 2.0:

Input: `+47(12)1234567`

Output: `+47121234567`

I tried to use this:

`replace(replace('$Input', '(',''), ')','')`

But it throws an error as '(' and ')' are unable to be escaped with the above code.

Please can some one point out the correct solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would put both characters into square brackets in a single `replace` call `replace($input, '[()]', '')`.

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses are reserved characters in regex, which is what the replace function takes as argument.

The easiest solution is to use `translate()`, in this case:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="translate('+47(12)1234567', '()', '')"/>
```

Alternatively, you can escape the parentheses with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `<xsl:value-of select="replace($input, '\(|\)','')"/>`

Comment: Can you add some explanation around your solution rather than just dumping code?